# Issue with nested grid (max-width preventing child elements from filling div)

Tags: html, css

First of all, apologies for my general lack of knowledge and any glaring mistakes i've obviously made!

I'm having trouble getting a nested grid to display images within a max-width container. As soon as I apply auto margins to get the content to sit within the center, it all squashes into a single column. This issue is resolved if the width is fixed, but of course i'd like it to shrink with the rest of the site on smaller screens.

This is likely complicated by the fact that i want my header/nav to have a fixed size larger than that of my main content area beneath. I need the main content area to be 950px, whilst maintaining the 1200px header/nav.

Here's a link to the site as it currently stands, the problem is with the "world" page...
[www.jamesofgalendar.com](https://www.jamesofgalendar.com)

```
.grid {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax( 200px, 1fr ) );
grid-template-rows: auto;
max-height: auto;
max-width: 1200px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 10px;
overflow: hidden;}

.nav {
grid-column: 1 / 5;
grid-rows: 1;
max-width: 1200px;
max-height: 294px;
vertical-align: bottom;
padding: 0px;
display: table-cell;}

.picture-grid {
grid-column: 1 / 5;
grid-rows: 2;
display: grid;
max-width: 950px;
grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax( 200px, 1fr ) );
grid-gap: 15px;
grid-row-gap: 15px;
background-color: #FF0;}

.grid-box{
width: 100%;
min-width: 0;}


<div class="grid">
<div class="nav">rollover images</div>

<div class="picture-grid">
<div class="grid-box"><img src="../images/book covers/template1.png" /></div>
<div class="grid-box"><img src="../images/book covers/template2.png" /></div>
<div class="grid-box"><img src="../images/book covers/template3.png" /></div>
<div class="grid-box"><img src="../images/book covers/template1.png" /></div>
<div class="grid-box"><img src="../images/book covers/template2.png" /></div>
<div class="grid-box"><img src="../images/book covers/template3.png" /></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with actual images.

Comment: In the meantime just change the `max-width` to `width:950px` and apply `margin auto`..that should work.

Comment: Hi Paulie, yes I've tried that before, though of course it won't allow the gallery to resize on smaller screens. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a good job for Flexbox styling inside your `.picture-grid`. You'd set your `.grid` container with the property `justify-items: center`, then change the `display` property of `.picture-grid` to `flex` and replace some of the grid styling options with flex options. Here's an example that got the result I think you're looking for:

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  /* i read in a tutorial about applying this type of column allocation. It still allows for subsequent column definitions, for example 1 / span 4. */
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  max-height: auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  justify-items: center;
}


.picture-grid {
  grid-column: 1 / 5;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-content: space-around;
  background-color: #FF0;
}

.grid-box {
  margin: 1%;
}
```

For more on Flexbox see this W3Schools article:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for that! I've not used flexbox at all, so this is completely new to me. I set the max-width of the .picture-grid to 950px and it fits perfectly. I'm going to check out the link you've left, but can i ask, was what i was trying to do impossible using a nested grid? I've been beating my head against this for weeks now, and only just plucked up the courage to ask people who would know! Thanks again!

Comment: To be honest, I'm pretty new to the CSS grid system as well! But I spent a while reading the documentation, and it seemed like it was intended for more rigid layouts, where flexbox is for more... well, flexible ones. But someone who's more of a wizard at it than I am might be able to correct me.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense. Most of the examples I found were using it to fit the screen, without separate size styling for specific devices. I made the mistake of designing my site for desktop and then had to think about breaking it down for smaller screens! Thanks again!